# Programatically set publishing options to Sitecore for specific language version

Tags: publishing, sitecore-api

I wanted my sitecore item to publish only a particular language version. For example, I have english and French, but I only want to publish the French language. My plan is to set the "`Publishable To`" fields of that particular language from "`Publishing Settings`".

[image]

I wanted that way so that if someone accidentally publishes the root item, it won't publish the languages of the child items that shouldn't be published just yet. Is this possible?

I have tried this:

```
item.Publishing.UnpublishDate = DateTime.Now;
```

But I this refers to the shared field of the item, not the one from the "`Publishing Settings`"

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fields which determine when given language version is publishable are `Valid From` and `Valid to` from the `Lifetime` section:

[image]

You can edit them using:

```
item.Publishing.ValidFrom
item.Publishing.ValidTo
```

or

```
item.Fields[Sitecore.FieldIDs.ValidFrom]
item.Fields[Sitecore.FieldIDs.ValidTo]
```

alternatively you can use `Hide Version` field from the `Lifetime` section:

[image]

and set it using

```
item.Publishing.HideVersion
```

You need to make sure that you set that values for every item which should not be published in that language. It's not enough to set it on root level only.

Comment: Thanks! It worked!